# long long is 8 bytes, but I get integer overflow?

Tags: c, gcc, integer, literals, integer-overflow

Suppose

```
  long long b = 5*1024*1024*1024; // 5 gigs, small enough for 64 bits
  printf ("%lu\n",sizeof(long long)); // prints 8 (bytes) = 64 bits
```

but the compiler complains:

```
  warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
```

Why does it overflow, what am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because the numbers on the right hand side are of type `int`, not `long long`, so `int` arithmetic is performed in the expression, leading to an overflow.

If you add `LL` to one of them, it'll promote them all.

Comment: darn, you're right. One always thinks of appending f or (casting) floats... but never longs :( Appreciate it.

Comment: @DervinThunk - it's easy to forget with constants.

Comment: More precisely, the constants are of type `int` ("integer" is a more general term, covering everything from `char` to `long long` and possibly more). And if you apply the `LL` to the right-most `1024`, you could still get an overflow; given `5*1024*1024*1024LL`, `5*1024*1024` is still evaluated as an `int` -- which can legally be as narrow as 16 bits. The most robust solution is probably to write `5LL*1024LL*1024LL*1024LL` -- or `5LL * (1LL<<30)`.

Comment: @KeithThompson ... or just `5LL<<30`.