# Why does long long n = 2000*2000*2000*2000; overflow?

Tags: c++, c, types, literals, integer-overflow

```
long long int n = 2000*2000*2000*2000;    // overflow

long long int n = pow(2000,4);            // works
long long int n = 16000000000000;         // works
```

Why does the first one overflow (multiplying integer literal constants to assign to a long long)?

What's different about it vs. the second or third ones?

Comment: `pow(2000,4)` uses .. `double`,  `2000*2000*2000*2000` uses `int`.

Comment: The first one is calculated using `int`. 2000 is an int. Not long long int

Comment: and why does it overflow?

Comment: Because the maximum 32 bit int value is `2^31 − 1` which is `2,147,483,647` is smaller than 2000* 2000* 2000*2000 and since all the 2000s are int the calculation is done as an int. Not as a long long int

Comment: Periodic reminder: What you do with the result of an operation does not affect how that result is computed.

Comment: It's a duplicate of [Long integer overflow in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44874465), but this ended up getting better answers than that had, so I closed that as a duplicate of this.  I think the question @Cody found is about something else: relative precision of huge floats, making 1ulp > 1.0.  Not integer overflow at all.

Comment: @Cody: I eventually found some good duplicates, like [3 \* 1000000000 overflows as an int, but the variable is long long. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42960290) and [long long is 8 bytes, but I get integer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15960955), but this one has the best answers so they should be dups of this.  (e.g. other questions have answers with mis-statements like *all* literals have type int, which isn't true for larger numbers.  Or that appending an LL to *any* of the constants would avoid overflow, rather than 1st or 2nd for operator precedence.)

Comment: TL:DR: **This seems like the current best canonical Q&A** I've found for overflowing expressions with integer literals, so I've dup-hammered or edited the dup list of others to point at this one.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks.  And though it's not a dup, it might be nice to cross-reference with "Why did `double d = 1 / 3;` give me 0?"

Comment: See also [reasons not to use 1000 * 1000 * 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359).

Answer (score 144):

Because `2000` is an `int` which is usually 32-bit. Just use `2000LL`.

*Using `LL` suffix instead of `ll` was suggested by @AdrianMole in, now deleted, comment. Please check his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66354839/7691729).*

By default, integer literals are of the smallest type that can hold their value but not smaller than `int`. `2000` can easily be stored in an int since the Standard guarantees it is effectively at least a 16-bit type.

Arithmetic operators are always called with the larger of the types present but not smaller than `int`:

- `char*char` will be promoted to `operator*(int,int)->int`
- `char*int` calls `operator*(int,int)->int`
- `long*int` calls `operator*(long,long)->long`
- `int*int` still calls `operator*(int,int)->int`.

Crucially, the type is not dependent on whether the result can be stored in the inferred type. Which is exactly the problem happening in your case - multiplication is done with `int`s but the result overflows as it is still stored as `int`.

C++ does not support inferring types based on their destination like Haskell does so the assignment is irrelevant.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229417/discussion-on-answer-by-quimby-why-does-long-long-n-2000200020002000-overf).

Answer (score 94):

The constants (literals) on the RHS of your first line of code are `int` values (*not* `long long int`). Thus, the mulitplications are performed using `int` arithmetic, which will overflow.

To fix this, make the constants `long long` using the `LL` suffix:

```cpp
long long int n = 2000LL * 2000LL * 2000LL * 2000LL;
```

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)

In fact, as noted in the comment by [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes), the `LL` suffix is only actually *needed* on either the first (leftmost) or second constant. This is because, when multiplying types of two different [ranks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488777/what-does-rank-mean-in-relation-to-type-conversion), the operand of lower rank is promoted to the type of the higher rank, as described here: [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators). Furthermore, as the `*` (multiplication) operator has [left-to-right associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the 'promoted' *result* of the first multiplication propagates that promotion to the second and third.

Thus, either of the following lines will also work without overflow:

```cpp
long long int n1 = 2000LL * 2000 * 2000 * 2000;
long long int n2 = 2000 * 2000LL * 2000 * 2000;
```

---

**Note:** Although lowercase suffixes (as in `2000ll`) are valid C++, and entirely unambiguous *to the compiler*, there is a [general consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10457391/10871073) that the lowercase letter, 'ell', should be avoided in `long` and `long long` integer literals, as it can easily be mistaken, *by human readers*, for the digit, `1`. Thus, you will notice that `2000LL` (uppercase suffix) has been used throughout the answers here presented.

Comment: `*` groups left to right, so only the left-most `2000LL` actually needs an LL suffix.  The others will all get implicitly promoted to `long long` as evaluation of the other 2 `*` operators proceeds.  Using LL on all of them is certainly not a bad thing; less for humans to worry about when reading code, but just for future reference.  [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5563000)

Comment: @PeterCordes I've incorporated your comment into my answer - hope you don't mind! I was a bit hesitant, at first, because the issue is (partially) dealt with in the other answers (particularly Werner's). Hopefully, though, I've explained the issue in more detail.

Comment: It's always a good thing when people find ways to improve posts based on comments, including borrowing some of the wording, especially on canonical Q&As like this which hopefully many future readers will eventually see.  Improving posts is exactly what comments are for, so cheers. :)  And yeah, I only noticed Werner's answer after commenting here.  Explaining this point is definitely good; while looking for duplicates (which I ended up closing as dups of this, because it has good answers), I found some which incorrectly stated that making *any* of the numbers LL worked.

Comment: Wouldn't that work also if the LL is on the third constant? The first two get multiplied in `int` arithmetic, but that's fine, because 2000*2000 fits in an `int`.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes, in the case of these particular four values, that would work. However, the aim of my answer is to address more general cases, in which the the promotion *must* be applied from the get-go. But I would also maintain that using the suffix on all four is the best/clearest coding style: if you want `long long` arithmetic, use `long long` operands.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Also note (perhaps more importantly) that `2000 * 2000` **will** overflow if `int` is 16-bits wide. IIRC, the C++ standard allows 16-bit `int`, 32-bit `long` and 64-bit `long long`.

Answer (score 50):

`2000*2000*2000*2000` is a multiplication of 4 `int` values, which returns an `int` value. When you assign this `int` value to `long long int n` the overflow already happend (if `int` is 32 bit the resulting value won't fit).

You need to make sure that the overflow does not occur, so when you write

```
long long int n = static_cast<long long int>(2000)*2000*2000*2000;
```

you make sure that you are doing a `long long int` multiplication (`long long int` multiplied with `int` returns a `long long int`, so no overflow in your case).

A shorter (and better way) is to write `2000LL` or `2000ll` instead of the `static_cast`. That gives the integer literal the right type. This is not needed for 2000 which fits into an `int` but it would be needed for higher values that don't fit into an `int`.

```
long long int n = 2000LL*2000*2000*2000;
long long int n = 2000LL*2000LL*2000LL*2000LL;
```

Comment: @AdrianMole: Presumably you could use C++ style casting, `static_cast<long long int>(2000)` to avoid the issue (though I usually drop the implied `int` part). That said, `2000LL` is way simpler in this case.

Comment: @AdrianMole `-Wold-style-cast` is not included in `-Wall -Wextra` though. I see no harm in C-style casts to non-pointer, non-reference types.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I use clang-cl *via* Visual Studio (with `/Wall`) and that **does** give the warning. Also, why use the do-anything C-style cast when the softer `static_cast` will suffice?

Comment: @AdrianMole You are right, `static_cast` would be a better alternative. I don't know why, but I was thinking more C than C++ here.

Comment: @AdrianMole Because it's less typing. :)

Comment: re _no harm in C style casts_ -- when reading the source code, any C-style cast is an automatic code review issue.  So leaving it that way wastes time and attention every time it is looked at again.  Function-style is the same number of characters.

Answer (score 30):

The other answers (as of this writing) appear to not have been explicit enough to answer the question as stated. I'll try to fill this gap.

> Why does the first one overflow (multiplying integer literal constants to assign to a long long)?

The expression

```
long long int n = 2000*2000*2000*2000;
```

is evaluated as follows:

```
long long int n = ((2000*2000)*2000)*2000;
```

where the steps are (assuming 32-bit `int`):

1. `(2000*2000)` is a multiplication of two `int` values that yields 4000000, another `int` value.
2. `((2000*2000)*2000)` is a multiplication of the above yielded `int` value 4000000 with an `int` value 2000. This would yield 8000000000 if the value could fit into an `int`. But our assumed 32-bit int can store a maximum value of 2<sup>31</sup>-1=2147483647. So we get overflow right at this point.
3. The next multiplication would happen if there hadn't been overflow above.
4. The assignment of the resulting `int` product would happen (if not the overflow) to the `long long` variable, which would preserve the value.

Since we did have overflow, the statement has undefined behavior, so steps 3 and 4 can't be guaranteed.

> What's different about it vs. the second or third ones?

- `long long int n = pow(2000,4);`

The `pow(2000,4)` converts `2000` and `4` into `double` (see [some docs on `pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)), and then the function implementation does its best to produce a good approximation of the result, as a `double`. Then the assignment converts this `double` value to `long long`.

- `long long int n = 16000000000000;`

The literal `16000000000000` is too large to fit into an `int`, so its type is instead the next signed type that can fit the value. It could be `long` or `long long`, depending on the platform. See [Integer literal#The type of the literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal) for details. then the assignment converts this value to `long long` (or just writes it, if the literal's type was `long long` already).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 19):

The first is a multiplication using integers (typically 32 bit). It overflows because those integers cannot store `2000^4`. The result is then cast to `long long int`.

The second calls the pow function which casts the first argument to `double` and returns a `double`. The result is then cast to `long long int`. There is no overflow in this case because the math is done on a double value.

Comment: `int` can be as narrow as 16-bit, and is on some modern embedded microcontrollers (like AVR or MSP430), so you need to worry about this for portability if the final value is > 32767.  (You're unlikely to find a C implementation with 64-bit `int`, although IIRC there are a rare few.  And historically int might not be exactly 32.)  It's hard to be precise without bloating answers, but you could say "using `int` (normally 32-bit)"

Answer (score 5):

You might want to use the following in C++ to understand this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cxxabi.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace abi;

int main () {
    int status;
    cout << __cxa_demangle(typeid(2000*2000*2000*2000).name(),0,0,&status);
}
```

As you can see, the type is `int`.

In C, you can use ([courtesy of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17290414/7194773)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define typename(x) _Generic((x),        /* Get the name of a type */             \
                                                                                  \
        _Bool: "_Bool",                  unsigned char: "unsigned char",          \
         char: "char",                     signed char: "signed char",            \
    short int: "short int",         unsigned short int: "unsigned short int",     \
          int: "int",                     unsigned int: "unsigned int",           \
     long int: "long int",           unsigned long int: "unsigned long int",      \
long long int: "long long int", unsigned long long int: "unsigned long long int", \
        float: "float",                         double: "double",                 \
  long double: "long double",                   char *: "pointer to char",        \
       void *: "pointer to void",                int *: "pointer to int",         \
       char(*)[]: "pointer to char array",      default: "other")


unsigned int a = 3;
int main() {
    printf("%s", typename(a-10));
    return 0;
}
```

Here the type of the expression is `unsigned int` because the type mismatch implicitly upgrades the type to the largest type between `unsigned int` and `int`, which is `unsigned int`. The `unsigned int` will underflow to a large positive, which will be the expected negative when assigned to or interpreted as an `int`. The result of the calculation will always be `unsigned int` regardless of the values involved.

**C**

The minimum default type of an integer literal without a suffix is `int`, but only if the literal exceeds this, does its type becomes an `unsigned int`; if larger than that it is given a type of a `long int`, therefore 2000s are all `int`s. The type of an *expression* performed on a literal however, using unary or binary operators, uses the implicit type hierarchy to decide a type, not the value of the result (unlike the literal itself which uses the length of the literal in deciding the type), this is because C uses type coercion and not type synthesis. In order to solve this, you'd have to use long suffixes `ul` on the 2000s to explicitly specify the type of the literal.

Similarly, the default type of a decimal literal is `double`, but this can be changed with a `f` suffix. Prefixes do not change the type of decimal or integer literals.

The type of a string literal is `char []`, although it is really a `const char []`, and is just an address of the first character in the actual representation of that string literal in `.rodata`, and the address can be taken like any array using the unary ampersand `&"string"`, which is the same value (address) as `"string"`, just a different type (`char (*)[7]` vs. `char[7]`; `"string"` i.e. `char[]` is not just (at compiler level) a pointer to the array, it *is* the array, whereas the unary ampersand extracts just the pointer to the array). The `u` prefix changes this to an array of `char16_t`, which is an `unsigned short int`; the `U` prefix changes it to an array of `char32_t`, which is an `unsigned int`; and the `L` prefix changes it to an array of `wchar_t` which is an `int`. `u8` is a `char` and an unprefixed string uses implementation specific encoding, which is typically the same as `u8` i.e. UTF-8, of which ASCII is a subset. A [raw (`R`) prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56710079/7194773) available only for string literals (and available only on GNU C (`std=gnu99` onwards)) can be prefixed i.e. `uR` or `u8R`, but this does not influence the type.

The type of a character literal is `int` unless prefixed with `u` (`u'a'` is `unsigned short int`) or `U` (`U'a'` is `unsigned int`). `u8` and and `L` are both `int` when used on a character literal. An escape sequence in a string or character literal does not influence the encoding and hence the type, it's just a way of actually presenting the character to be encoded to the compiler.

The type of a complex literal `10i+1` or `10j+1` is `complex int`, where both the real and the imaginary part can have a suffix, like `10Li+1`, which in this case makes the imaginary part long and the overall type is `complex long int`, and upgrades the type of both the real and the imaginary part, so it doesn't matter where you put the suffix or whether you put it on both. A mismatch will always use the largest of the two suffixes as the overall type.

Using an explicit cast instead of a literal suffix always results in the correct behaviour if you use it correctly and are aware of the semantic difference that it truncates/extends (sign extends for `signed`; zero extends for `unsigned` – this is based on the type of the literal or expression being cast and not the type that's being cast to, so a `signed int` is sign extended into an `unsigned long int`) a literal to an expression of that type, rather than the literal inherently having that type.

**C++**

[image]

Again, the minimum default type is an `int` for the smallest literal base. The literal base i.e. the actual value of the literal, and the suffix influence the final literal type according to the following table where within each box for each suffix, the order of final type is listed from smallest to largest based on the size of the actual literal base. For each suffix, the final type of the literal can only be equal to or larger than the suffix type, and based on the size of the literal base. C exhibits the same behaviour. When larger than a `long long int`, depending on the compiler, `__int128` is used. I think you could also create your own literal suffix operator `i128` and return a value of that type.

The default type of a decimal literal is the same as C.

The type of a string literal is `char []`. The type of `&"string"` is `const char (*) [7]` and the type of `+"string"` is `const char *` (in C you can only decay using `"string"+0`). C++ differs in that the latter 2 forms acquire a `const` but in C they don't. The string prefixes behave the same as in C

Character and complex literals behave the same as C.

Comment: @MaksimKuzmin The question has the appearance of simplicity, yet it hides the underlying system representation of numbers at CPU level and how C/C++ language deals with it. In fact, it's not a so simple question, so this very elaborate answer is meaningful and useful regarding the question.

Comment: @Zilog80 yeah I just wanted a guide on literals to refer back to

Comment: @LewisKelsey You means it would have been better to put links to the literals documentation instead of embedding it, and i fully agree. I was mainly pointing the fact that numbers representation at CPU level worths a bit of elaboration [but not indeed an embedded excerpt of documentations].