# Next power of 2

Tags: c++

I have 2 similar pieces of code which take a number and return the next power of 2
They return the same result up until 1e9, any larger and the second function returns an incorrect answer, why is that?

```
unsigned long long nextPowerOf2(unsigned long long n) 
{ 
    unsigned long long p = 1; 
    if (n && !(n & (n - 1))) 
        return n; 
  
    while (p < n)  
        p <<= 1; 
      
    return p; 
}
unsigned long long nextPowerOf(unsigned long long n)  //returns incorrect answer if n>1e9
{  
    unsigned long long count = 0;  
      
    if (n && !(n & (n - 1)))  
        return n;  
      
    while( n != 0)  
    {  
        n >>= 1;  
        count += 1;  
    }  
    cout << "weird?: " << count << endl;
    return (1 << count);  
}
```

Comment: `return (1 << count);` what happens if count is equal to or bigger than the bit size of int?  Did you mean `return 1ULL << count;`?

Comment: That did it, i didnt think it would matter since the function returns ull anyway and its not stored in a variable. so why is that?

Comment: Especially when dealing with bitwise operations, it may be useful to express numbers in hexadecimal or binary instead of decimal. That tends to make it more obvious when you cross a "magic boundary" such as 2^32 (or 2^31 for signed values).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does long long n = 2000\*2000\*2000\*2000; overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354756/why-does-long-long-n-2000200020002000-overflow)

Comment: @Yosefahab try `1ULL << count` instead. If you used clang (visual studio, etc) it would warn you that you're doing implicit casts.

Comment: It seems like @JaMiT said 'magic boundary' that was crossed, i know anything bigger than 1e9 would overflow an integer thats why i specified my types as unsigned long long. 
Apparently you need to cast the return value to ULL explicitly even without a variable, i'm guessing thats compiler behaviour ?

Comment: The `1 << count` results in an `int`.  The evaluation of that expression is irrelevant that the return will be an `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was returning (1 << count) would overflow and you need to cast it as said in the comments.
So

```
return (1ULL << count);
```

fixes it.